# ant sql task classpath problem

Tags: sql, ant, classpath

I have the following ant `build.xml`:

```
<path id="antclasspath">
    <fileset dir="lib">
        <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</path>

<property name="pathvar" refid="antclasspath" />
<echo message="Classpath is ${pathvar}"/>

<sql
    driver="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
    url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@myserver.hu:1521:dbid"
    userid="myuserid"
    password="mypassword"
    print="yes"
    classpathref="antclasspath">
    select * from table
</sql>
```

There is an Oracle JDBC driver in the lib directory. Echo prints it out correctly:

```
Classpath is E:\MyDir\lib\ojdbc14-10_2_0_3.jar
```

Somehow sql ant task is still not able to load the Oracle driver:

```
E:\MyDir\build.xml:100: Class Not Found: JDBC driver oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver could not be loaded
```

What is the problem with this build.xml? It is quite strange that it was working few times yesterday, but never again.

Using `classpath="E:\MyDir\lib\ojdbc14-10_2_0_3.jar"` in the task gives the same error message.

I'm using ant 1.7.1 (built in Netbeans 6.5)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax looks correct to me.  Try passing the `-v` switch to your ant command, that will direct the `sql` task to print out the classpath it's using.  You should see something like:

```
[sql] connecting to jdbc:oracle:thin:@myserver.hu:1521:dbid
[sql] Loading oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver using AntClassLoader with classpath E:\MyDir\lib\ojdbc14-10_2_0_3.jar
[sql] Executing commands
[sql] SQL:  select * from dual
[sql] Processing new result set.
[sql] DUMMY
[sql] X

[sql] 0 rows affected
[sql] 0 rows affected
[sql] Committing transaction
[sql] 1 of 1 SQL statements executed successfully
```

If that doesn't help, you can try passing the `-debug` switch, which will print out reams of information including classloader debugging.

Finally, have you verified that your ojdbc jar is not corrupt and does, in fact, contain the OracleDriver class?

Comment: Yes, the jar file was corrupted -v switch gave me an error message. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the class name to oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver. The oracle.jdbc.driver package is being deprecated in favour of oracle.jdbc.

See the section "The Old oracle.jdbc.driver Package Will Go Away" in the readme [here](http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/tech/java/sqlj_jdbc/htdocs/readme_10201.html).

Comment: Does not help. The error message changes according to the rename.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the classpathref attribute you could try using classpath element.

```
<sql ..params..>
  <classpath refid="antclasspath"/>
</sql>
```

This is how I always reference my classpaths and I have never had any issues.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately I've got the same error message.